# Mongoose update only updates first document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Okay.. this is odd and annoying, so any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Here's my code:

```
        Target.update {location_city: "New York"}, {location_country: "FUDGE!"}, {safe: true}, (err, res) ->
          console.log "Updating with New York"
          console.log res
          console.log "Err #{err}"
```

No error, NADA. BUT only the FIRST document gets updated for some reason. When I run a find on the SAME query, I get multiple results.

Any help would be AWESOMELY appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`multi` has to be `true`.

So the correct query would be

```
    Target.update {location_city: "New York"}, {location_country: "FUDGE!"}, {multi: true}, (err, res) ->
      console.log "Updating with New York"
      console.log res
      console.log "Err #{err}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't find this in Mongoose's documentation though I find it hard to believe that they would leave out such an important switch.